# How to set layers, scale, center automatically and default zoom based on JSON file config?

Tags: openlayers, json

I want to know how I can init my OpenLayers 3 `Configuring the Viewer by JSON file (layers, scale, center and default zoom)` at the start of my application from a JSON configuration file.

***My app.js:***

```
var ol = require('openlayers');
var jQuery = require('jquery');

map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    zoom: false,
    attribution: false
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform(
      [3.6656, 45.9192],
      'EPSG:4326',
      'EPSG:3857'
    ),
    zoom: 6
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to make a JSON element accessible is to put it in a JavaScript file. As an example, create a file `mapSettings.js` in the same directory as your other JavaScript file. Then define your JSON object like this

```
var mapConfig = {
        "lat": 15,
        "lon": 35,
        "zoom": 4,
        "layer": "https://myLayerUrl.com/layer/"
    };
```

Now you can inlude `mapSettings.js` using `<script src="mapSettings.js"></script>` in the HTML head. The defined variables are now accessible from the other JavaScript file using e.g. `mapConfig.lat`.

You can set the view center to the location specified in your JSON file with

```
yourMap.getView ().setCenter (
ol.proj.transform ([xCoordinate, yCoordinate], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

and then define the desired zoom level with

```
yourMap.getView().setZoom(yourZoomLevel);
```

after the map has been loaded.

Note: You may have to edit the EPSG codes according to your needs. This sample works with geographic coordinates.

Comment: ok so how can declare my `json` file in my `app.js` ?

Comment: Sorry, from your initial question I thought you only wanted to know how to pass the variables to the OL element. I'll edit the answer accordingly.